# D-bus monitoring does work from the command line, but not as a systemd service

Tags: systemd, d-bus

I wrote a bash script reading SMS messages using the ModemManager, mostly with `mmcli`. It works fine from the command line, but not when started as a systemd service.

I quickly found out that this line is the core of the problem:

```
/usr/bin/gdbus monitor --system --dest org.freedesktop.ModemManager1
```

When I start it from a command line, it prints a line every time a SMS message is received by my USB modem. This is what was expected and what I need.

Example output (commented):

```
# at the start
Monitoring signals from all objects owned by org.freedesktop.ModemManager1
The name org.freedesktop.ModemManager1 is owned by :1.5

# when a message arrives
/org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.PropertiesChanged ('org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.Modem.Messaging', {'Messages': <[objectpath '/org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/SMS/19']>}, @as [])
/org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.Modem.Messaging.Added (objectpath '/org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/SMS/19', true)
```

After adding a service file, when I start the same script as a systemd service, it does not do the same. The `gdbus` outputs only the same two lines at the start and nothing more. The `gdbus` says it is monitoring, but it isn't. SMS messages are coming in, but remain unnoticed.

I checked that the service is running, script is running, `gdbus` is running, same user ID. Running as root does not help either.

What makes the difference between the command line and systemd? How could I fix it?

---

The service file - nothing special

```
[Unit]
Description=Read incoming SMS messages
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=exec
User=smsuser
Environment=LANG=en_US.UTF-8
ExecStart=/bin/bash /opt/sms/sms_read_service ModemNameArg
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

---

Updates:

I got it to work with:

```
# shortened for brevity
busctl --system monitor ... --match type='signal',interface='...',member='...'")
```

but only as root. I think it can be explained with a D-Bus security policy.

The question - what causes the difference whe using `gdbus` - remains.

Comment: When you run the script in the shell, do you run it as root, or as a non-privileged user? What happens if you restart the service, is it the same? Can you show your sms_read_service script?

Comment: @aviro at the command line: `sudo -u smsuser SCRIPT ...` and it works fine. Restarting does not help. The whole script is not interesting IMHO, basically it is a `gdbus monitor .... | while read line` loop and the issue is when no lines are coming from the monitor.